# Common javascript form validation not working

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to use the following javascript code to validate several fields on a contact form. The validation works for the first item being validated, the name field, but not the second, the email field. If the name field is filled in, the validation seems to skip over the email field check when it's blank and the form submits.

```
function validateForm() 
{

    var n = document.contact.name.value;
    n = n.trim();

    var ema = document.contact.email.value;
    ema = ema.trim();

    //Check if the name is missing
    if (n == null || n == "" || empty(n)) 
    {
        alert("Please enter your name.");
        document.contact.name.focus();
        return false;
    }

    //Check if the email is missing
    else if ( ema == null || ema == "" || empty(ema) )
    {
        alert( "Please enter your email address." );
        document.contact.email.focus();
        return false;
    }  
    else
    {
        return( true );
    }
}
```

Here is the HTML on the contact form:

```
<FORM name="contact" METHOD="POST" ACTION="thankyou.php"  onsubmit="return validateForm()">

    <input type="checkbox" name="newsletter" value="YES" width="30" height="30"> Check the box to subscribe to Herb's Newsletter

    <input type="text" class="form-control" size=20 name="name" placeholder="Your name" />

    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" />

    <input class="btn btn-theme btn-subscribe" type="submit" value="Send" />

</form>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be using `empty` function in your `if` clauses which doesn't seem to be defined nor it is part of the standard javascript functions. Try getting rid of it:

```
function validateForm() {
    var n = document.contact.name.value;
    n = n.trim();

    var ema = document.contact.email.value;
    ema = ema.trim();

    //Check if the name is missing
    if (n == null || n == "") {
        alert("Please enter your name.");
        document.contact.name.focus();
        return false;
    } else if (ema == null || ema == "") {
        //Check if the email is missing
        alert( "Please enter your email address." );
        document.contact.email.focus();
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

And here's a [live demo](https://jsfiddle.net/p79rq562/1/).

Answer (score 0):

In your code you use else if statement.

Basically what you code does is:
`check name -> if that is falsy check email -> if that is falsy move into else condition`.

But when the name is true, the if statement will not move to `else` conditions because it it already satisfied. So if you want to check both, you either separate the statements and make a 5 separate ifs, make it a switch statement or you create one long check. For example:

```
if ((n == null || n == "" || empty(n)) || ( ema == null || ema == "" || empty(ema) )) 
{
    alert("Something is missing");
    return false;
}  
else
{
    return( true );
}
```

or you use multiple ifs:

```
function validateForm() {

var n = document.contact.name.value;
n = n.trim();

var ema = document.contact.email.value;
ema = ema.trim();

//Check if the name is missing
if (n == null || n == "" || empty(n)) 
{
    alert("Please enter your name.");
    document.contact.name.focus();
    return false;
}

//Check if the email is missing
if ( ema == null || ema == "" || empty(ema) )
{
    alert( "Please enter your email address." );
    document.contact.email.focus();
    return false;
}  
return( true );
}
```

The latter will always return true unless one of the if statements is triggered.

And see answer below about the empty() thing. I don't know what that is and if it messes anything up.